# Matlab Barcode Reader

Tags: matlab

I have the following code in matlab to decode a barcode:

```
barcode = imread('barcode.jpg');
imshow(barcode);
pause;

barcode = rgb2gray(barcode);
barcode = histeq(barcode);
barcode = imresize(barcode, .35, 'bilinear');

imshow(barcode);
pause;

%level = graythresh(barcode);
%bw = im2bw(barcode, level);
h = edge(barcode, 'sobel', [], 'horizontal');

% dilate the horizontal edges vertically to get rid of noise
se = strel('line',20,1);
h = imdilate(h, se);
imshow(h);
pause;

v = edge(barcode, 'sobel', [], 'vertical');
se = strel('line',1,20);
v = imdilate(v, se);
imshow(v);
pause;

regions = ~h & v;
imshow(regions);
pause;

% dilate image to get barcode region
se = strel('line',9,1);

% get the barcode region
regions = imdilate(regions,se);
imshow(regions);
pause;

%regions = imcomplement(regions);

[labels,numLabels]=bwlabel(regions);
imshow(label2rgb(labels, @spring, 'c', 'shuffle'));
pause;


% find largest region
index = 0;
largest_size = 0;
for i = 0:max(unique(labels))
    if sum(sum(regions & (labels == i))) > largest_size
        largest_size = sum(sum(regions & (labels == i)));
        index = i;
    end
end

% show largest region
imshow(regions & (labels == index));
pause;

region = regions & (labels == index);
region = imcomplement(region);

% extract region from original barcode image
[rows, cols] = size(region);
for i = 1:rows
    for j = 1:cols
        if region(i,j) == 1
            barcode(i,j) = 255;
        end
    end
end

imshow(barcode);
pause;

% we now have extracted the barcode

% sharpen it a little bit
yar = fspecial('unsharp');
barcode = imfilter(barcode,yar,'replicate');
imshow(barcode);
pause;

% get the highest/lowest x & y values
x1 = cols;
x2 = 1;
y1 = rows;
y2 = 1;
for i = 1:rows
    for j = 1:cols
        if region(i,j) == 1
            if i < y1
                y1 = i;
            end
            if i > y2
                y2 = i;
            end
            if j < x1
                x1 = j;
            end
            if j > x2
                x2 = j;
            end
        end
    end
end

[r,c] = size(barcode);

for i = 1:r
    for j = 1:c
        if barcode(i,j) >= 194
            barcode(i,j) = 255;
        end
        if barcode(i,j) < 194
            barcode(i,j) = 0;
        end
    end
end

%imshow(barcode);

% COPIED/PASTED FROM http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21899-recognize-barcode/content/runprogram.m
I=barcode;
I=im2bw(I);             
imshow(I);  
hold on;
[x,y]=ginput(2);        %get data from click mouse
u1=x(1);
u2=y(1);
v1=x(2);
v2=y(2);
line(x,y);              %paint the line between 2 point at click mouse
a = (u1:1:v1);          %find out function line between 2 point
if (u1~=v1) && (u2~=v2)
    g = round(((v2-u2)/(v1-u1))*a + u2 -(u1/(v1-u1)));
elseif (u1==v1)
    a = u1;
end                      
i=1;                    %find the value each pixel that the line go through
h=v1-u1+1;
b=(1:1:h);
for a=u1:v1
    if (I(g,a)==0)
        b(i)=1;
        i=i+1;
    elseif (I(g,a)==1)
        b(i)=0;
        i=i+1;
    end
end
c=b;
i=1;                %find number pixels of each line in barcode picture;
s=(1:1:60);
for k=1:60
    j=0;
    curr=c(i);
    while (c(i)==curr)&&(i<=h)
            j=j+1;
            i=i+1;
    end
    s(k)=j;
end
mau=s(2);       %the first line is the sample for barcode,in another line is ratio with this
q=s./mau;
p=round(q);     

doc1=(1:1:6);   %decode 
k=1;
for i=5:4:25
    if (p(i)==3)&& (p(i+1)==2) &&(p(i+2)==1) &&(p(i+3)==1)
        doc1(k)=0;
    elseif (p(i)==2)&& (p(i+1)==2) &&(p(i+2)==2) &&(p(i+3)==1)
        doc1(k)=1;
    elseif (p(i)==2)&& (p(i+1)==1) &&(p(i+2)==2) &&(p(i+3)==2)
        doc1(k)=2;
    elseif (p(i)==1)&& (p(i+1)==4) &&(p(i+2)==1) &&(p(i+3)==1)
        doc1(k)=3;
    elseif (p(i)==1)&& (p(i+1)==1) &&(p(i+2)==3) &&(p(i+3)==2)
        doc1(k)=4;
    elseif (p(i)==1)&& (p(i+1)==2)&&(p(i+2)==3) &&(p(i+3)==1)
        doc1(k)=5;
    elseif (p(i)==1)&& (p(i+1)==1) &&(p(i+2)==1) &&(p(i+3)==4)
        doc1(k)=6;
    elseif (p(i)==1)&& (p(i+1)==3) &&(p(i+2)==1) &&(p(i+3)==2)
        doc1(k)=7;
    elseif (p(i)==1)&& (p(i+1)==2) &&(p(i+2)==1) &&(p(i+3)==3)
        doc1(k)=8;
    elseif (p(i)==3)&& (p(i+1)==1) &&(p(i+2)==1) &&(p(i+3)==2)
        doc1(k)=9;
    end
    k=k+1;
end
doc2=(1:1:6);
k=1;
for i=34:4:54
    if (p(i)==3)&& (p(i+1)==2) &&(p(i+2)==1) &&(p(i+3)==1)
        doc2(k)=0;
    elseif (p(i)==2)&& (p(i+1)==2) &&(p(i+2)==2) &&(p(i+3)==1)
        doc2(k)=1;
    elseif (p(i)==2)&& (p(i+1)==1) &&(p(i+2)==2) &&(p(i+3)==2)
        doc2(k)=2;
    elseif (p(i)==1)&& (p(i+1)==4) &&(p(i+2)==1) &&(p(i+3)==1)
        doc2(k)=3;
    elseif (p(i)==1)&& (p(i+1)==1) &&(p(i+2)==3) &&(p(i+3)==2)
        doc2(k)=4;
    elseif (p(i)==1)&& (p(i+1)==2) &&(p(i+2)==3) &&(p(i+3)==1)
        doc2(k)=5;
    elseif (p(i)==1)&& (p(i+1)==1) &&(p(i+2)==1) &&(p(i+3)==4)
        doc2(k)=6;
    elseif (p(i)==1)&& (p(i+1)==3) &&(p(i+2)==1) &&(p(i+3)==2)
        doc2(k)=7;
    elseif (p(i)==1)&& (p(i+1)==2) &&(p(i+2)==1) &&(p(i+3)==3)
        doc2(k)=8;
    elseif (p(i)==3)&& (p(i+1)==1) &&(p(i+2)==1) &&(p(i+3)==2)
        doc2(k)=9;
    end
    k=k+1;
end
```

The problem is that it doesn't seem to read it correctly!

I was also having some trouble on the `ginput` part, where the user must create a line on the barcode image for it to read the pixels over the line.

Can you guys help me out in finding the actual problem?

Thanks!!

Comment: 1. Include your image in your question 2. All the barcodes don't have the same encryption 3. Be precise, which part of your code don't work ?

Comment: I think it does not work from where I draw the line on the image with the ginput comand...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure that the type of barcode that you are trying to decide is what you are providing it as there are many different types of barcodes. =

I have tried your provided code with just an image of a barcode and it appears to have issues finding the barcode area, as well the code that you have copied from mathworks does not reliably decode the barcode;

I would recommend taking a look at the link below; it provides an simulink model, however, all the code can be seen or moved to a m-file, or you can adapt your code into it... It is set up for EAN13 (UPC).

As for the ginput not working, I personnally wouldn't leave it to the user to select the scan line. You could get multiple lines at angles by introducing a simple rotation to the image and with this you can effectively scan for any orientation (like the scanners at the grocery store). However, with that being said, you need to round the inputs `u1 u2 v1 v2` as they can be decimals and you are using them as indices later in your code.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/barcode-recognition.html

Comment: First of all thanks for the help! Now, one more thing. How can I move the code to an m-file?

Comment: You can open each block, and it opens up the block editor... Ctrl+C, Ctrl +V